# `:m +ModuleName` is not executed in `.ghci`

Tags: ghci

I from the manual I take that a `.ghci` file is executed each time `ghci` is started.

I execute my executable with `cabal repl`. In the directory above the Haskell source is my `.ghci` which includes

```
:set -fno-warn-incomplete-patterns
:m +LinAlg
```

but the `:m +LinAlg` is not executed (and I have to enter after each start of `.ghci`).

I have tried to put the `.ghci` file in my home dir `~` but no change. What do I do wrong?